# restrict installation path

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation

How do I restrict the user to a single install path on their machine?  I saw another thread suggesting ' use registry " but not sure how

I am using VB.NET 2008

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Setup And Deployment project type? Just add that to your solution and you'll have plenty of options to play with.